# Woocommerce product name

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

For a purpose im passing woocommerce values to an array like this :

```
    'name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
    'phone' => $_POST['billing_phone'],
    'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
    'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],
```

Now I'm stuck finding one of the values. The name of the ordered product.

[image]

```
'subject' => HERE GOES THE PRODUCT NAME VALUE,
```

i have been looking everywhere, tried some stuff but nothing worked so far.

I'm working in `functions.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can retrieve the order ID, you can do this

```
  $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  $items = $order->get_items();
```

Then you can loop through results to add the product name to your array.

```
  foreach($items as $item){
         $product_names .= $item['name'] .' ';
  }
```